# How should I start this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that the vector [1, 1] is an eigenvector of a matrix A corresponding to the eigenvalue 3 and that [2, 1] is an eigenvector of A corresponding to the eigenvalue -2. Compute $A^2$ [4, 3].

Can someone please guide me on where to start? 
Thank you

Comment: Very similar problem here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784261/finding-matrix-a-from-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-diagonalization/1784277#1784277

Comment: Cat's answer to the linked problem should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\pmatrix{1\\1} = \pmatrix{3\\3} \mbox{ and } A\pmatrix{2\\1} = \pmatrix{-4\\-2} \implies A\pmatrix{1&2\\1&1}=\pmatrix{3&-4\\3&-2}
$$
And since
$$\pmatrix{1&2\\1&1}^{-1} = \pmatrix{-1&2\\1&-1}$$ 
$$A = \pmatrix{3&-4\\3&-2}\pmatrix{-1&2\\1&-1} = \pmatrix{-7&10\\-5&8}
$$
Then you can find $A^2\pmatrix{4\\3}$ by simple matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to the way Fischler described. However, say that you want to compute $A^k$ for some natural $k$ (large). Then you want to diagonalise $A$. You know a basis and the eigenvalues, so for matrix with the eigenvectors as columns $V$ and diagonal matrix (with eigenvalues) $\Lambda$ you get
$$
A = V \Lambda V^{-1} \implies A^k = (V\Lambda V^{-1})\dots(V\Lambda V^{-1}) = V\Lambda^k V^{-1},
$$
where $\Lambda^k$ is just the eigenvalues to the $k$:th power. Substitute $k=2$, and this is an alternative solution.